# What is the origin of Marathi and Konkani case endings (specifically genitive and accusative-dative)?

Tags: historical-linguistics, comparative-linguistics, sanskrit, declension, indo-aryan

In Konkani and Marathi, the genitive case ending is -च (cha) with a vowel attached to the end depending on the gender. I am curious to know the origin of this case ending.

Is there potential of a derivation from Sanskrit च (meaning "And", but at certain times, denoting "With)? च is usually used as a particle post-positionally and it is not far fetched to assume a semantic shift from "and/with" to "attached to" to finally "belonging to".

Dialectally there is also the suffix -गेले used to denote genitive case for animate objects in certain dialects (Marathi 'Majhe' vs Goan 'Majhe' vs Canara 'Magele'). Is there any information as to the origin of this ending. It is also attested in use as a dative case. Is there any relation to the Marathi Accusative-Dative ending of -ला?

I have read that even in dialects that do not primarily use -गेले as a suffix sometimes use it in the plural, which makes me wonder if there is a connection to the suffix -গুলো "gulo" used in Bengali for plural words.